# Nil cannot be assigned to type ()->()?

Tags: swift, swift3

So this is a function from a class that lets you have a double tap and a single tap gesture. It's working fine in Swift 2.3, but after converting to Swift 3 it's throwing a few errors. I can't understand/figure out for the life of me. I commented where they occur.

```
//  UIShortTapGestureRecognizer.swift
//
//

import Foundation
import UIKit


    func delayHelper(_ time:TimeInterval, task:@escaping ()->()) ->  DelayTask? {

        func dispatch_later(_ block:@escaping ()->()) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
                deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(time * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC),
                execute: block)
        }

        var closure: ()->()? = task

        var result: DelayTask?

        let delayedClosure: DelayTask = {
            cancel in

//Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '() -> ()?'
            if let internalClosure = closure {
                if (cancel == false) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: internalClosure)
                }
            }

// here it says Nil cannot be assigned to type '() -> ()?'
            closure = nil

            result = nil
        }

        result = delayedClosure

        dispatch_later {
            if let delayedClosure = result {
                delayedClosure(false)
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    func cancel(_ task:DelayTask?) {
        task?(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: It means the return parameter is optional. Try (() -> ())?

Comment: I am somewhat doubtful this would've compiled in Swift 2.3 either, it should have also considered `()->()?` to be a function that returns `Void?`.

Answer (score 6):

Try with: `var closure: (()->())? = task`

Answer (score 0):

[From another topic:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652771/closure-with-default-value-as-function-parameter)

```
func someFunction(someParameter: someType, completionClosure: @escaping @autoclosure () -> ()? = nil)
```

The use of @autoclosure allowed me to assign nil to the optional closure.

The full details of how exactly @autoclosure helps escape me (why "my" closure is "not good" but the Swift_generated_one_that_simply_wraps_mine is?) . 
But, it helped me get rid of ...
[image]
 ...and call my function in either of two ways:

```
someFunction(x, { ... })
```

OR

```
someFunction(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how i could overcome this. Here clang is not aware about its type. I gave a typealias and optional declaration,

```
typealias appDelegateBlock = ()->()
```

In your class, just declare it as optional,

```
var block: appDelegateBlock?
block = task
```